# How to reduce the horizontal space between two side by side columns in the title and author part?

Tags: spacing, minipage

The following code corresponds to the title and authors of a paper.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\centering
\veryHuge \textbf{Title Title Title Title Title Title}\\
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\Large \textbf{AAAAAAAAAAA}\\
\large XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\YYYYYYYYYYYYY
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\Large \textbf{BBBBBBBBBBB}\\
\large XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\YYYYYYYYYYYYY
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

which generates as follows:

[image]

How do I reduce the space between the two columns in the code so that it compiles as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Where/How is `\veryHuge` defined?

Comment: @leandriis I edited the code. It is now compilable. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\centering{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\Huge \textbf{Title Title Title Title Title Title}
\end{minipage}\par \vspace*{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\Large \textbf{AAAAAAAAAAA}\\
\large XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\YYYYYYYYYYYYY
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\Large \textbf{BBBBBBBBBBB}\\
\large XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\YYYYYYYYYYYYY
\end{minipage}
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: why not upvote then

Comment: I have accepted this answer, but as my reputation is less than 15 in this community, it doesn't show the upvote...